# Check the checkbox on run-time

Tags: oracle, oracleforms, ora-06502

I have a data block called `LOAN` and item called `DOC_8` which is a checkbox. On run-time I would like to check the checkbox item `DOC_8`. When using the following code:

```
:LOAN.DOC_8 := 'Y';
```

I got the following error

> FRM-40735: POST-QUERY trigger raised unhandled exception ORA-06502.

Please help, I'm very new to this.

Comment: "The following code" is one thing (that's what users do when they click the checkbox". POST-QUERY trigger is another; it fires when you execute query and fetch data from the database. So, what's written in there?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Error `ORA-06502` raises due to two cases occur:

1. If the value doesn't fit in a variable, or *data type* violated
2. A *NULL* value is assigned to a variable which's defined as *NOT
   NULL*

It seems in your case that the **Data type** in your checkbox's **Property Palette** is not defined as a *string*, perhaps *numeric*.